# check existence of record on user in an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a user that has_many associations. Associations has a provider field. I want to check if a user has a provider. If provider were a field on the user table I would just do `provider.blank?` How do I do the same check when reaching through a has_many association?

EDIT:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :authentications

end

class Authentications < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

end
```

Authentications table has the following fields

```
:provider
:user_id
:uid
:id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if any of the user's Authentications contain providers using the following:

```
user.authentications.any? {|a| a.provider }
```

[`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) iterates over the Array and returns `true` if the block returns true when passed each element of the Array. When the Array is empty (i.e., no Authentications) it returns `false`.

Comment: a user has_many association. provider is a field in the associations table.

Comment: Actually, I just completely changed it again, now that I think I better understand your question. I think you should use `has_many :through`, see latest edit

Comment: providers isn't a model, it's just a field in the authentications table, which I'm trying to check if it's blank.

Comment: That worked. I thought there would be a much simpler solution. Kind of like how I can write user.provider because of the has_many association